# angular 4, why to Write CSS in component? considered good or bad?

Tags: angular

i am writing css in component file css, add it using stylesURL in ts file, and also writing in main sytles file styles.css
which is considered as good practice.
what are pros and cons of writing in component/styles.css file

Answer (score 0):

The [Angular website](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles) gives a pretty good idea on why it is considered an improvement with respect to modularity:

> - You can use the CSS class names and selectors that make the most sense in the context of each component.
> - Class names and selectors are local to the component and don't collide with classes and selectors used elsewhere in the application.
> - Changes to styles elsewhere in the application don't affect the component's styles.
> - You can co-locate the CSS code of each component with the TypeScript and HTML code of the component, which leads to a neat and tidy project
>     structure.
> - You can change or remove component CSS code without searching through the whole application to find where else the code is used.

Comment: This is not the whole truth. There are not only advantages, especially when overused. We can see it as an additional structuring mechanism but there are still cases where one wants to have global styles (for example to support themes).

Comment: @Henry absolutely. This is why I stated that it is considered an improvement with respect to modularity.

Comment: I wouldn't say that one has to go for component styles ONLY. The global stylesheet has a right to exist.